# jquery get innter text

Tags: jquery

Here is some code:

```
jQuery.each(comments, function(i, comment)
{
    cl.append("<div class='comment_entry' id='" + comment.id + "' style='background-color: " + colors[color] + ";'><div class='ce_time'>" + comment.time + "</div><div class='ce_poster'>" + comment.poster_name + "</div><div class='ce_comment' id='ce_comment'>" + comment.comment + "</div></div>");
    color = 1 - color;
});

jQuery(".comment_entry").click(function()
{
    //alert(this.ce_comment);
    alert(jQuery('this').find('#ce_comment').text());
});
```

What I am doing here is adding DIVs on the fly. Then, I am adding a click event to the DIVs by their class. When a DIV is clicked, it should display the text in the DIV ID 'ce_comment'. Instead, I get a blank. I know there is text in the DIV because I can see it on the page.

SO, what is the correct way to access the text in this case?

Comment: There can be only one element with id `ce_comment`, probably you should use `ce_comment` class to access text inside clicked comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `this`.

```
jQuery(this).find('#ce_comment').text()
```